# entering extended mode restricted \write18 enabled

Tags: xetex, compiling

I recently updated miktex and reinstalled Texmaker. Everything was working fine. But today, I tried to compile a file with Xelatex, there is a message in the log that I do not understand. It is the same with Pdflatex and Luatex. For Pdflatex for instance, it is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.4.6) 6 APR 2022 14:45
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
```

Could someone please help me?

Here is the minimal example :

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

I danse

\end{document}
```

Comment: that is normal. It means that xelatex (and pdflatex) is allowed to execute applications from a restricted list. With pdflatex this is for example used to convert an eps to pdf on-the-fly with epstopdf.  You can disable it in miktex with `-disable-write18`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I disable it with the code you sent me? I mean, where do I go to do that? Thanks

Comment: that is a option for the xelatex/pdflatex call. But why do you want disable it?

Comment: I am writing my thesis and everything was fine. Then this came out (The pdf of my thesis does not show up when I compile it with xelatex). I need everything to be like it was.

Comment: What is your actual error? Why do you believe that disabling the restricted mode will resolve it?

Comment: I can show you the log. The issue is that I've never activated this mode myself. Moreover, the pdf of my thesis is blank when I compile it. It was not like so far. I also have to click on the button view pdf in order for it to actualize it.

Comment: the mode is activated by default. Everyone has it. So stop looking at it and try to find out what is really wrong.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am going to try to find what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I divided my thesis in different tex files that I included in the main document with the command \include{}. Then, I made him display the part I am currently working on. But it was not displaying again. So, I compiled all the parts and it worked. Now I can compile the part I am currently working on now.